# regexp fails over expression involving {}

Tags: regular-expressions, query-replace-regexp

Over:

```
\includepdf[pages={1-}]{example-image-a.pdf}
```

I do / get

```
M-x query-replace-regexp \\includepdf[pages={1-}]{.*} → \\includepdf[pages={1-}]{TEST}
Replace 0 occurrences
```

The problem comes from the trailing `{}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, the problem comes from the unescaped `[` and `]`.

```
M-x query-replace-regexp \\includepdf\[pages={1-}\]{.*} → \\includepdf[pages={1-}]{TEST}
```

works for me.